# Map and filter confusion

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm in little confusion about map and filter function, please help me to sort out my problem.

Here is my code. I want to highlight only the selected row. But now the whole row get highlighted when I select one row.

```
  {DocumentList && DocumentList.map(Doc =>
 <tr key={Doc.DocID}  className={selectedDocumentsForAttach.length !==0 && selectedDocumentsForAttach.filter(o => (o.DocID === Doc.DocID))?"print-table-row_hyLight":'print-table-row'}>
```

Comment: add `.length > 0`  or `length !== 0` at the end of your `.filter` method. SO it returns a boolean. Otherwise the condition won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ternary condition should evaluate to a boolean. Instead of .filter you should use .some which returns true if at least one of your argument function calls returns true. [Cf. MDN](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwio45a2suvkAhUECxoKHfXXBcIQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0YEs17qhTXHYYSI1DZIjvO)

Answer (score 1):

Filter will return an array so you have to use `.length` with `.filter` function. Try the below condition for you highlight class,

```
<tr key={Doc.DocID}  className={
     (selectedDocumentsForAttach.length && // checking .length is enough for true value
      selectedDocumentsForAttach.filter(o => (o.DocID === Doc.DocID)).length
     ) ? 'print-table-row_hyLight' : 'print-table-row'}>
```